# Hints to using Git on a Windows PC for a project coded and managed with Unix?

Tags: git

I am the only person on a Windows computer to code on a project. The rest are using Unix computers.

The server is also Unix-based. What precautions do I need to take regarding setting up Git?
And In particular the part where it provides the 3 line-ending options…

Comment: If you're able to use a sensible text editor which is able to work with Unix-style EOLs, and would preserve them when editing existing files, I would recommend to actually set `core.autocrlf` to `false` locally.  You might want to temporarily set this option to `false` *globally* before initial cloning of the master repository, then revert the global setting and set it locally in the clone.

Comment: Check the repo for filename collisions after case flattening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on what tools you and your colleagues are using. Since you're the only person using Windows, I'm assuming that the codebase is already using Unix-style line-feeds instead of Windows-style carriage-return + line-feeds.

If that is the case, then you can either work locally with Windows line-endings and have Git automatically convert text files to Unix style when you commit, or you can work with Unix line-endings locally, and just set your editor to use them.

To have Git automatically convert Windows style endings to Unix style, use

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```